# Flutter How I Can add ground overlay to google maps without divide the image into small square pieces

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

I am working on flutter mobile project that require to add an image "Real estate project layout" to map to allocate the units "Apartments, Villas, etc.." on it .
How I can achieve this without divide the image to small pieces to use the Tile overlay